# Submitting Specific Submit Button

Tags: jquery, html, form-submit

In my HTML code, there are several submit buttons, I've assigned an specific ID to the submit buttons, but when it goes to jQuery part only first submit button works. Other submit buttons return false.

HTML (in PHP file) I'm using is;

```
$sid = intval($sid);
$comment_box = '
    <div class="comment_box_tcat"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="comment_box" sid="'.$sid.'">Post Comment</a></div>
    <div id="comment_box_show_'.$sid.'" style="display: none;">
        <div id="latest_comments">'.get_latest_comments($sid).'</div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <textarea name="message" id="comment_message" maxlength="'.$mybb->settings['mystatus_chars'].'" value="" style="resize: none;" cols="35" rows="3" tabindex="4"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" name="sid" id="sid" value="'.$sid.'" />
            <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" value="'.$mybb->user['uid'].'" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="5" id="comment_submit_'.$sid.'" onClick="return false;">
        </form>
    </div>';
```

and jQuery is;

```
// Post Comment
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('input[id^="comment_submit_"+sid]').on('click', function ()
    {
        var message = $("#comment_message").val();
        var sid = $("#sid").val();
        var uid = $("#uid").val();

        if (!message)
        {
            alert('Message is missing.');
            return;
        }

        $.ajax(
        {
            type : "post",
            dataType: "html",
            url : "status.php?action=do_post_comment",
            data : "message="+message+"&uid="+uid+"&sid="+sid,
            success : function(response)
            {
                $('#latest_comments').html(response).show();
                document.getElementById('comment_message').value = '';
                document.getElementById('comment_message').focus();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I only see one submit button in your html...

Comment: The `$comment_box` variable is inside a `while()` loop, so it shows for each `sid`

Comment: please pass an object instead of a string for `data`. otherwise YOU need to take care of properly encoding the values. also, why do you mix vanilla js and jquery in the same function?!

Comment: @user2854563 "vanilla" is like saying "plain" - using javascript without a library like jQuery. He means that it's silly to use `getElementById` if you're already using jQuery. You might as well select it the jQuery way `$('#comment_message').val('')`.

Comment: I have given you an appropriate answer for your question...I would appreciate it you would mark it as accepted. You didn't agree with it at the time, but as you can see by the upvotes, I am correct.

Answer (score 3):

**You're selector would need to be: `$('input[id^="comment_submit_"'+sid+']')`, which uses the `sid` variable. You're not defining that variable until after the above selector is used, so your current architecture is flawed.**

Further, **id's are supposed to be unique, but you're reusing them in the loop, and that's going to throw off everything.** Most of your code is just a thrown together mess that show little understanding of html and javascript.

**Your question is an** [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I recommend you make another post on SO describing your project (what are you trying to do overall and why?) and explain what you have tried (like this example) so that people know you're at least trying to come up with something. Then people can make suggestions on a good approach to your issue to help get you started with a good foundation.

Comment: The submit button triggered if I use this: `$('input[id^="comment_submit_"]').on('click', function ()` but on next submit button (for next sid) it doesn't trigger.

Comment: @user2854563 of course not, read my answer. You seriously need to delete all of this (both php and javascript) and start over. The major source of your problem is the reuse of id's. You can only use an id once in an html document. I just said this in my answer.

Comment: No sorry, I do not want to waste my time writing the code again. Your answer is absolutely useless for me..

Comment: @user2854563 heh, you wasted your time writing it to begin with. It can't work. I told you exactly where your problems are. You can fix them if you want....and spend a lot of time trying to make awful code do what you want. Or you can spend some time learning how to write good code and never have these problems again.

Comment: @user2854563 by the way, if you follow my advice and make a post that isn't an x/y problem, any decent programmer could write up a good example of how to do this properly in about 10 minutes.